# How can I automatically scale this equation to graph how I want?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have the equation:

$y = a  b^x \times \sin^2(\pi x)$

I am only interested in the output between x=0 and x=1. I would like the curve to peak at y=1 in this range by automatically scaling "a" to accomplish this based on any given setting for "b".

That way it will look similar to:

$y = \sin^2(\pi x^c)$

Both equations are graphed here showing approximately what I mean:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e4glcythvs

Any suggestion for how I can write $a$ in the first equation to accomplish this for varying levels of $b$?

Comment: You can divide $y$ by $ab^{x_0}$, where $x_0$ is the value of $x$ when $y=1$.

Comment: @Mike In your link, the first equation is $ab^x \sin^2(\pi x)$, while your question statement gives $ab^x \sin^2(x)$. Based on the context, e.g., $0 \le x \le 1$, I assume the link's equation is what you want. If so, please edit your question text to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks John, yeah they were both supposed to be pi*x as in the desmos link. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the extrema $x_e$ of $f(x) = b^x \sin^2(\pi x)$:
$$
\partial_x b^x \sin^2(\pi x) = b^x\sin(\pi x)(\ln(b)\sin(\pi x)+2\pi\cos(\pi x)) \Rightarrow x_e = \text{arccot}(-\tfrac{\ln(b)}{2\pi})\tfrac{1}{\pi}
$$
and then just set $a = f(x_e)^{-1}$, i.e.
$$f(x)\to \frac{1}{b^{x_e}\sin^2(\pi x_e)}b^x \sin^2(\pi x)$$

Comment: This only holds, if $x_e \in (0,1)$. Otherwise take $a = f(1)^{-1}$

Comment: Hi Denklo, I tried what you were suggesting but it didn't seem to work or I'm doing it wrong or not understanding. Can you please provide the final version of the y = a * b^x * sin^(pi*x) equation with "a" replaced by an expression of b? I tried to implement what you were saying here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3mwtcdeo1q

Comment: You have to normalize by $f(a)^{-1}$, not $a$.

Comment: @Mike Found a missing factor $\pi^{-1}$ in my $x_e$ above. When plugging it in in your desmos link, it seems to work well.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x9j4z57oly

Comment: Thanks so much! Works nicely.